# Adicionar fotos e galeria a um produto ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Eu estou iniciando em asp.net usando mvc 5, ja fiz algumas cursos bases, e agora quero fazer uma loja virtual simples pouco complexa. mas estou numa duvida crucial na tabela produto, ele vai ter uma foto miniatura e mais as outras na sua descrição,

```
public class Produto
{

    public int PRODUTOID { get; set; }

    public int CATEGORIAID { get; set; }

    public string NOME { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Imagem")]
    [DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
    public string FOTO { get; set; }

    public decimal PRECO_UNITARIO { get; set; }

    public string QUANTIDADE_ESTOQUE { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Categoria> Categoria { get; set; }
}
```

Minha duvida é como faço para adicionar mais imagem a esse produto quando a pessoa for ver detalhes do produto? eu teria que criar outra tabela "galeria" e relacionar com o produto em questão?

Comment: Se você quer ter um número ilimitado de imagens para o seus produtos, o que é mais comum, você precisará criar outra tabela para guardar essas urls. Se for um número restrito, você pode simplesmente adicionar novas colunas como FOTO_UM, FOTO_DOIS e etc... (O que não é nada elegante)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, é possivel fazer tudo numa `string` so

voce pode colocar todas a images no mesmo campo `FOTO` e separar as fontos usando `";"` e quando o usuario fizer a chamada vc so precisa adionar o `.split(";")` e retorna a lista de imagens.

exemplo:

```
string[] fotos= FOTO.Split(';');
```